# Combining each element of a list to elements of another list in R

Tags: r, list

I have two list

```
list_1 <- list('A', 'B', 'C')

list_2 <- list('X', 'Y')
```

if  I want the resultant list to be of the form

```
list_3 <- list('AX', 'AY', 'AZ', 'BX', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ')
```

The final list should be all possible combinations of the elements in both the lists without duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
do.call(paste0, expand.grid(list_1, list_2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
as.list(outer(list_1,list_2, paste0))
```

Information regarding [`outer`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/outer)